# RecylerView Lags when adding Images from Drawable to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am loading images into ArrayList and then setting it to RecylerView with GridLayout. The images are loaded and everything looks good. But when I scroll the RecylerView it starts lagging.Though images are loaded completely there is a lag while scrolling.

Some answers I came across were about lazy loading the images or using Glide or Picasso libraries. But how can I implement it?
Here's how I am adding images.

MainActivity:

```
int imageArray[] = new int[]{
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,...
};
private ArrayList prepareData(){
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        myModel.setDrawable(imageArray[i]);
        arrayList.add(myModel);
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Here's my Adapter code:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

   viewHolder.tv_logo.setImageResource(mArrayList.get(i).getDrawable());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Glide then use following code to load your drawable image into imageview using Glide

```
 Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.yourImage).into(imageView);
```

Where "context" is your activity context 
and "imageView" is your object of ImageView

Comment: I am not using either Glide or Picasso and I need to add this code where?

Comment: you have to add   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0' in your .gradle file and then use above code in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the native code of your network calling library that show images, and also if there is a sort of lagging, you can add progress bar in your image view for good user experience and also try to use AppCompatImageView instead of ImageView in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Glide or Picasso for image loading.

Try this

```
Glide.with(yourContext).load(imageArray[position]).into(viewHolder.tv_logo);
```

Image loading would be smooth and fast.

You can try Picasso also.

Happy Coding :)